# "Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread" after upgrading from Spring framework 4.1.9 to 4.2.x

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-4.x

I am currently in the progress of upgrading our project from Spring framework 4.1.9 to 4.2.4, but I am encountering a comlpicated problem.

After upgrading, the following exception occurs:

```
* ERROR 09:51:34,033 Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@4ef7145f] to prepare test instance [org.hisp.dhis.attribute.AttributeServiceTest@1611ce1c] (TestContextManager.java [main])
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.createRequestAndRun(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.executeEager(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2207)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4790)
    at org.hisp.dhis.setting.DefaultSystemSettingManager.getSystemSetting(DefaultSystemSettingManager.java:169)
    at org.hisp.dhis.sms.config.DefaultSmsConfigurationManager.getSmsConfiguration(DefaultSmsConfigurationManager.java:103)
    at org.hisp.dhis.sms.config.DefaultSmsConfigurationManager.initializeSmsConfigurables(DefaultSmsConfigurationManager.java:66)
    at org.hisp.dhis.sms.config.DefaultSmsConfigurationManager.onApplicationEvent(DefaultSmsConfigurationManager.java:201)
    at org.hisp.dhis.sms.config.DefaultSmsConfigurationManager.onApplicationEvent(DefaultSmsConfigurationManager.java:48)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:335)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:855)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:993)
    at org.hisp.dhis.hibernate.HibernateGenericStore.getClazzCriteria(HibernateGenericStore.java:251)
    at org.hisp.dhis.hibernate.HibernateGenericStore.getCriteria(HibernateGenericStore.java:195)
    at org.hisp.dhis.hibernate.HibernateGenericStore.getCriteria(HibernateGenericStore.java:263)
    at org.hisp.dhis.setting.hibernate.HibernateSystemSettingStore.getByName(HibernateSystemSettingStore.java:45)
    at org.hisp.dhis.setting.DefaultSystemSettingManager.getSystemSettingOptional(DefaultSystemSettingManager.java:188)
    at org.hisp.dhis.setting.DefaultSystemSettingManager.lambda$getSystemSetting$1(DefaultSystemSettingManager.java:170)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4793)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3542)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2323)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2286)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2201)
    ... 55 more
```

This is just one version of where the exception occurs. During my time trying to resolve it, the exception keeps occuring at different places.

Needless to say, before upgrading, everything worked perfectly.

To let you know what I have done already (which all failed):

- Upgrading to 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3 and 4.2.4 all result in the same problem
- Can't seem to find any relevant changes from changelogs and issues resolved in the 4.2.* versions
- Some of the exceptions occurs in methods with @PostConstruct. Seemingly since they call methods with the @Transactional, but not always (Like in the case posted here). As a solution, I have tried three things:

  - Using TransactionTemplates (failed, same exception)
  - Using Callback from ApplicationListener (Using ContextRefreshedEvent). Changed up the order in which exceptions happend, but same core problem.
  - Changing the order of which the beans are loaded, by adding depends-on on the problem beans. (No change)

We are also using Hibernate 4.2.2.

This is a big project, so it's not easy to know which code is relevant to post and what kind of information might be needed to solve this, so I can post updates with more info if requested.

Hope someone could tell me what changed in the 4.2.* versions that could cause this. Any ideas and help are greatly appriciated!

Edit: Added configuration/beans for hibernate/transactions as requested:

```
<!-- Transactions -->

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Configuration -->

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.hisp.dhis.cache.DefaultHibernateCacheManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="dbmsManager" class="org.hisp.dhis.dbms.HibernateDbmsManager">
  <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateConfigurationProvider" class="org.hisp.dhis.hibernate.DefaultHibernateConfigurationProvider">
  <property name="configurationProvider" ref="dhisConfigurationProvider" />
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateMappingDirectoryLocations" class="org.hisp.dhis.hibernate.HibernateMappingDirectoryLocationsFactoryBean">
  <property name="hibernateConfigurationProvider" ref="hibernateConfigurationProvider" />
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateMappingJarLocations" class="org.hisp.dhis.hibernate.HibernateMappingJarLocationsFactoryBean">
  <property name="hibernateConfigurationProvider" ref="hibernateConfigurationProvider" />
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateProperties" class="org.hisp.dhis.hibernate.HibernatePropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="hibernateConfigurationProvider" ref="hibernateConfigurationProvider" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties" />
  <property name="mappingJarLocations" ref="hibernateMappingJarLocations" />
  <property name="mappingDirectoryLocations" ref="hibernateMappingDirectoryLocations" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClass" ref="driverClass" />
  <property name="jdbcUrl" ref="url" />
  <property name="user" ref="username" />
  <property name="password" ref="password" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" ref="maxPoolSize" />
  <property name="acquireIncrement" value="6" />
  <property name="maxIdleTime" value="7200" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="fetchSize" value="1000" />
</bean>

<bean id="driverClass" class="org.hisp.dhis.hibernate.ConnectionPropertyFactoryBean">
  <property name="hibernateConfigurationProvider" ref="hibernateConfigurationProvider" />
  <property name="hibernateProperty" value="hibernate.connection.driver_class" />
</bean>

<bean id="url" class="org.hisp.dhis.hibernate.ConnectionPropertyFactoryBean">
  <property name="hibernateConfigurationProvider" ref="hibernateConfigurationProvider" />
  <property name="hibernateProperty" value="hibernate.connection.url" />
</bean>

<bean id="username" class="org.hisp.dhis.hibernate.ConnectionPropertyFactoryBean">
  <property name="hibernateConfigurationProvider" ref="hibernateConfigurationProvider" />
  <property name="hibernateProperty" value="hibernate.connection.username" />
</bean>

<bean id="password" class="org.hisp.dhis.hibernate.ConnectionPropertyFactoryBean">
  <property name="hibernateConfigurationProvider" ref="hibernateConfigurationProvider" />
  <property name="hibernateProperty" value="hibernate.connection.password" />
</bean>

<bean id="maxPoolSize" class="org.hisp.dhis.hibernate.ConnectionPropertyFactoryBean">
  <property name="hibernateConfigurationProvider" ref="hibernateConfigurationProvider" />
  <property name="hibernateProperty" value="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" />
  <property name="defaultValue" value="40" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Post your configuration next to that you shouldn't be calling transactional beans from `@PostConstruct` beans as there might not have been any transactional proxies created yet and your transactions will fail.

Comment: Which configuration are you interested in? The bean xml files? They are split up and rather large. Or are you referring to some other configuration?

I will rewrite all @PostConstruct methods using transactions to wait for the ContextRefreshedEvent, but it seems like that doesn't resolve the problem by itself (Same exception is thrown, only later).

Comment: The hibernate or em and transaction configuration and as this is a test maybe your test case.

Comment: Added the bean definitions for the hibernate/transactionManager, was this what you meant?

Comment: Which properties are you passing into the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`? That is hidden in some factory...

Comment: Your `current_session_context` seem to be configured correctly there is however nothing transactional related in your stack trace. Looks like you have some circular dependency issue leading to eager instantiation for a bean that is setting up the configuration which in turn is needed again to instantiate hibernate.

Comment: Among a multitude of other problems, circular dependencies was one of them. Thanks for the tip, it helped us look in the right direction! :) We have finally been able to upgrade to spring 4.2.5 with no further problems :)